# Is there a way to compare two hand-drawn drawings?

Tags: drawing, compare, html5-canvas

For an experiment, we are looking for a way to automatically compare two hand (mouse-)drawn images. These images are, for instance, drawn on an HTML5 canvas element and we need some way to see whether the pictures roughly match.

So, if someone draws a house, we need to test whether the second drawing looks like the first house. It doesn't matter what exactly is in the image, but we only need to know whether the two images look alike. I.e., we want to know whether the person drawing the picture, can redraw roughly the same picture. The exact orientations of the lines, the size of the image or the position of the picture on the canvas shouldn't matter.

Is there, by any chance, a library or project that does this?

Comment: Really? I'd be surprised

Comment: opencv ? but i don't get what you want to compare and in what properties you are interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, we didn't find a library that does exactly the same, so we have modified the original project's goals and have crowdsourced the comparison that needed to be done.

You can probably also use [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) or something similar for the time being, depending on how much you wish to pay for it.

I think researchers are currently be working on technical solutions to the issue described above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely

> With API provided by Face.com and with imagemagick Both are providing
>   api's
>   http://www.imagemagick.org/api/compare.php
>   FaceAPI - Track Faces from a Webcam: http://faceapi.com

it might be useful for your requirement